# mongodump: fact.bson: input/output error

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.0, mongodb-3.2

We are trying to export 1.5TB database into mongodb. But its fail after 100gb and giving us below error. As we notice root mount point got 100% space. We are using below command:

mongodump -u admin -p xx_admin_db -d xx --host xx.xx.xx.xx --authenticationDatabase admin

```
2018-06-28T12:20:30.687+0000    [........................]  xx1.fact  14679565/468546715  (3.1%)
2018-06-28T12:20:31.192+0000    [........................]  xx1.fact  14680477/468546715  (3.1%)
2018-06-28T12:20:31.195+0000    Failed: error writing to file: write dump/xx/xxx.bson: input/output error
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the --out/-o parameter to indicate a directory on a filesystem where you have enough room.

Comment: relevant mount point have sufficient space but we dont know why our root mount points is going to 100% fill.

Anything copying into "/" mount point from mongodump utility ???

Comment: start the dump, while it is running, run "find / -xdev -mmin -5 -type f"  (I hope mongodump does not create a file, and deletes it without closing).   BTW, what do you consider the "relevant mount point"?   What is $PWD when you run mongodump?

Comment: we moved into mount point with 2TB size and mongodump use this mount point but during backup why root "/" mount point filled 100% ??

Comment: Maybe you're mistaken about the mount.  You're not answering my questions.  Can you add the output of "mount" to your question?  If you execute the "find", you will have the answer to "why root mount point filled 100%".

Comment: Perhaps "dump" is a symbolic link to "/" ?

Comment: Go to the root, and give command `du -ms *|sort -n` to find out what directory is taking all free space. Then go to that directory and repeat command.. Until you know what takes all free space!